# Why can't we use .append with string object in Java?

Tags: java

I can't understand why the following code is showing an error:

```
import java.lang.StringBuffer.*;
import java.io.*;

class chk
{
    public static void main() 
    {
        System.out.print('\u000c');
        String k = "catering";
        * String l = k.append(5); // shows error here
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Is it that we can't access methods from other classes (for example, the `Stringbuffer` class) from the `String` class?

Comment: Of course you can't. Why would there be classes and types if you could?

Answer (score 0):

> String l=k.append(5); (shows error here)

`append(int i)` is the method of `StringBuffer` not of `String`.

If you want to append any to string use `+`.

```
 String l=k+5;
```

---

```
public StringBuffer append(int i)
```

> Appends the string representation of the int argument to this
>   sequence.

We can't invoke the methods of `StringBuffer` class with the object of `String` class. Since there is no relationship between these two classes means parent-child.